# How to locate parent theme functions and add functions to my wordpress child theme?

Tags: php, css, child-theme

I am using a wordpress child theme and have added css code to the style.css and everything works well. When i want to add function to my function.php file I always get error message. I am new to using the child theme so my problem is to know where to place functions. Should all new functions be placed inside funtion.php or does it depend on each function.

function.php file:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'PRANAYAMA_YOGA_THEME_VERSION'; // 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
```

For example i tried to add a onepage-nav function to my Menu, like this

```
  $('#nav').onePageNav({
    currentClass: 'current',
    changeHash: false,
    scrollSpeed: 750
  });
 /
```

But my site crashed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: crashed by the php function?

Comment: yes, when I insert this function in the php file the site crashes. I dont know exactly what it is that makes it crash but something about adding this function to the php file.

Comment: can you set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` so to display the error. you can find inside `wp-config.php`

Comment: That’s not a PHP function. That’s JavaScript. You can’t put JavaScript in functions.php like that.

Comment: Yes that what i was thiking, I am new to using the wordpress child theme and placing the functions. Do I have to make a function and then call the function in the function.php folder ?